# How to know the active Qt Widget in the current window?

Tags: qt

The application I'm working on has a QTabWidget with 3 tabs, and all the tabs have QStackWidget added to it with variable number of widgets present at a time.
When I RMB on a particular widget inside a particular tab, its eventFilter gets called and a context menu pop up.

I have to add this RMB context menu behaviour on top as Banner Menu. And this Banner menu is not written in Qt but in some internal which can be converted into C++ using wrapper.

Now my problem is that when I RMB on a widget its eventFilter easily tells me address of the object ie: *this* and I can add appropriate slots to context menus.

But in the case of banner menus, how would I know the address of the object whose slots() I have to call. The banner menus are supposed to work for the selected/currently-visible widgets.

Comment: Did you try to search among widgets in the active tab and currently active stack widget?

Comment: What is a "banner" menu?

Comment: Your issue is not quite clear. But maybe you'll find `QObject::sender()` or `QWidget::isVisible` functions helpful.